# Node/Mongoose - Trouble creating objects in an array if they don't already exist during update

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

all. This has been stumping me since yesterday, and any help would be greatly appreciated. My User model has arrays of other models, like so:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({               
addresses           : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                         ref: 'Address' 
                      }]
```

Now, when running the update function in my controller, I would like to update an object if it is already present in the array, or create a new one if it is not. I am, in the instance of address, using the addressType property from the model to check and see if the address already exists in the array.

In my usersController:
create function:

```
function createAddress(req, res){
User.findOne({ user_id: req.params.id}, function(err, user){
    Address.create(req.body, function(err, address){
        user.addresses.push(address)
    })
})
```

}

and here is a snippet of the update function:

```
function updateUser (req, res) {
console.log("updating user in back end")
User.findOneAndUpdate({user_id: req.params.id}, req.body, function(err, user){
if(err) throw err

        Address.findOne({address_id: req.params.id}, req.body, function(err, address){
            if(err) throw err
                if({addressType: req.params.id} != req.body.addressType){
                    createAddress(req);
                } else {
                    Address.findOneAndUpdate({address_id: req.params.id}, req.body, function(err, address){
                if(err) throw err
                    })
                }
```

It seems like it would work, but every time I run it, i get a new object in the database, even if I'm sending the exact same info via postman. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2):

```
if({addressType: req.params.id} != req.body.addressType)
```

You compare object with string. It is always `not equals`.

```
if (address) {
  update();
} else {
  create();
}
```

And better is to use `upsert` option:

```
Address.findOneAndUpdate({address_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {
  upsert: true
}, callback);
```

[Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)